# Can Adsense auto ads (page-level ads) and DFP slots exist on same page

Tags: google-adsense, advertising, google-adsense-policies, google-dfp

I am currently switching all my Adsense ad units to DoubleClick. The reason is to server multiple networks including Adsense.

However, DFP doesn't support auto ads.  Hence, I have to leave without removing the auto ads code on header. The ideas is Adsense auto ads will fill those places where DFP tags are not present. But will auto ads recognize DFP tags and leave DFP slots unaffected?